# Recognising key words within a spoken sentence

Tags: c#, speech

I have a program that can recognise speech so the user can dictate to it and it will recognise the words.

I want to extend this to be able to allow the user to say "Computer, search on wikipedia for XXXXX" and have my program load the search page of wikipedia, searching for XXXXX.

How do I achieve this?

For Example

```
else if (e.Result.Text == "Search on Wikipedia for <string>")
{
    say("Searching for <string>"); 
    get_Wiki_info(); 
    say("The definition for <string> is <Wikipediaresult>")
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have a program that you can dicatate words to, but you now want it to do different things depending on what you say to it? (For example you say "Search on wikipedia for XXXXX" it should open the search page on wikipedia for XXXXX). If so, then the speech part of the question can be removed, since you've already solved that. You just need to recognise different meanings from the different words.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to what I think you're trying to ask. Please edit it again/back if I've got it wrong (or leave a comment here if you can).

Comment: I've edited the Text as you say and I've given a short example...

Comment: So your actual question should really be: "How do I fetch info from Wikipedia programatically"? Is that correct?

Comment: My question is, how can i realize it in grammar, that i cut the Question string, get and save the <string>-part, to use it.

Its nessasary to insert the <string> into the Searchlink

Here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/<string>

Answer (score 0):

One option would to simply strip off the question portion:

```
else if (e.Result.Text == "Search on Wikipedia for <string>")
{
    string searchToken = e.Result.Text.Substring("Search on Wikipedia for".Length).Trim();
    say("Searching for <string>"); 
    get_Wiki_info(searchToken);
    say("The definition for <string> is <Wikipediaresult>")
}
```

Then take the search token during the search.

```
private void get_Wiki_info(string searchToken)
{
  //Do Wikipedia Search
}
```